# Which laws simplify this boolean expression?

Tags: boolean-expression, simplification, boolean-algebra

Which laws do I need to use to simplify

```
!X + (!Y + !Z)*(Y + Z)
```

to

```
!X + (Y*!Z) + (!Y*Z)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `+` and `*`? Boolean `OR` and `AND`?

Comment: yes, sorry I thought that was equivalent

Comment: Try "multiplying out" the second term in the original expression. Then you can find rules that simplify the longer expression. Also, I don't think this question is completely appropriate for this site because it's not related to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first start by distributivity of multiplication over addition:

```
!X + (!Y + !Z)*(Y + Z) = !X + !Y*Y + !Z*Y + !Y*Z + !Z*Z
```

Then, we can use complementation to remove elements of the form `!p*p`:

```
= !X + 0 + !Z*Y + !Y*Z + 0
```

And finally remove the `0` as they are `+`'s neutral.

Answer (score 2):

No need to apply any specific 'laws', just write down a simple table to figure out the two expression are equivalent (providing `+` is `OR` and `*` is `AND`):

```
Y  Z  !Y  !Z  (!Y+!Z)*(Y+Z)      (Y*!Z) +(!Y*Z)
0  0  1   1   (1+1=1)*(0+0=0)=0  (0*1=0)+(1*0=0)=0
0  1  1   0   (1+0=1)*(0+1=1)=1  (0*0=0)+(1*1=1)=1
1  0  0   1   (0+1=1)*(1+0=1)=1  (1*1=1)+(0*0=0)=1
1  1  0   0   (0+0=0)*(1+1=1)=0  (1*0=0)+(0*1=0)=0
```

Likewise you can deduct that `(X or Y) and Z` is equivalent to `(X and Z) or (Y and Z)`. This is called distributivity of `and` over `or`. Further reading is a nice article about [*Boolean algebra*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) on Wikipedia.

In your example: `(!Y + !Z)*(Y + Z) = !Y*(Y + Z) + !Z*(Y + Z) = !Y*Y + !Y*Z + !Z*Y + !Z*Z`. Trivially `A and not A == false`, then your expression simplifies to `!Y*Z + !Z*Y` and further to `Y*!Z + !Y*Z` because of commutativity.

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves (and I take your notation correctly), then that's an SLD resolution inside a simple conjunction: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLD_resolution